# Map Ubuntu drive to Windows machine

Tags: networking, windows, samba

So there is plenty of answers to the opposite question but I need to be able to access and modify my files on my Ubuntu machine from my Windows 7 machine.

What have I tried already?

It looks like I have Samba installed (somehow) but I've spent so much time just now installing packages to install other packages, fixing installs and finding out what and why I don't have parts of some packages installed to enable other things to be installed that I just don't know! (I'm a bit of an Ubuntu newb in case you can't see...)

My `/etc/samba/smb.config` has been modified to look like this:

```
#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each 
# user's home director as \\server\username
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
    read only = no

...

# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
    valid users = %S
```

Restart Samba `sudo service smbd restart`.

Now back in my Windows machine I try and map to my Ubuntu drive with `\\[my-machine-name]\[my-machines-admin-user]`. The little dialog comes up asking me for a Network Username and Password so I enter the credentials aaaaaaand... it tells me that it is no good. I can see the user I am logging in with is not just `[ubuntu-username]` but `[my-windows-machine]\[ubuntu-username]`... ??

I'm tired, any help? There's not too much info out there on the web for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At Ubuntu Machine open terminal

```
sudo smbpasswd -a USERNAME
```

where USERNAME is your user name

Comment: Ah, ah, ah! That's it! Oh man, thank you! Haha.
(I'm sorry I can't vote you up, don't have enough rep 'round here!)

Comment: between @One Zero I also want to access my Ubuntu files into Windows 7. Can you please detail me bit from a scratch as to what I need to do. Some tutorial reference link would also do.